# Identify this hub (similar to a Sturmey Archer rear internal gear hub w/ drum brake)

Tags: hub, internally-geared-hub, identify-this-bike

I recently came across the auction of  an old Gazelle city bike. It is equipped with rear internal gear hub with drum brake which looks like Sturmey Archer 3 gear hub. But this hub has two shifting cables (one on each side, going to the internal hub) and very strange shifters, which I guess are not original.

The auction description states that this is 3 gear hub.

I've seen Sachs Pentasport 5 hear hub with similar shifting design, so I suppose it might be something similar.

Please, help my curiosity and identify the model of the hub.

[image]
[image]

EDIT
on the handlebar I've noticed some kind of gear shifting instruction, which suggest there is indeed 5 gears.
[image]

[Auction](http://sprzedajemy.pl/rower-meski-gazelle-holender-28-nr35908937)

Comment: Interesting.  Is that front hub a generator or a drum brake?  I note that the cranks are "modern" (not cottered), so if the crank's original then the bike is likely newer than 1975 or so.  It's not clear what you consider to be "strange" about the shifters.

Comment: Those stem shifters suggest an 80s design, and may not be original.  Normally the left one is for the front mech and the right one is for the rear mech, and pulling the lever moves to a larger cog.   Can you follow the wires and see where they go, if anywhere?   Is the front crank a single chainring under that chaincase, or does it have two or three?

Comment: On hindsight, the bike has no rim brakes.  Therefore it has to be drum brakes down on both hubs, and one of the wires to the rear hub must control this.  The wire on the chain side will be the control for the gear selector.

Comment: @Criggie - My 1973 Raleigh 5-speed had a stem shiifter.  By 1980 many designs had shifted to downtube shifters.

Comment: @DanielRHicks front hub for sure is equipped with drum brake and not with generator. I guess the bike was produced in mid 80s.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Such shifters were common in gears with derailleurs, where one was responsible for shifting front gears, other for rear. In this case two independent shifters operate one hub. I saw similar design with one shifter, responsible for setting only "legal" settings of two cables. In this case cyclist would be the one who would be responsible for this and I'm pretty sure that if this is sometking like Sachs Pentasport, not all settings (let's say there is 3*3 settings) are legal. As far as I know in Pentasport concept one cable was responsible for gears 1,3,5 and the other for 2 and 4.

Comment: @Criggie - Looking at the pictures, you can see cables (of the sort used for geared hubs) entering the hub on both ends of the axle.  You can also, on the left side, see the rod and lever of a drum brake.  So there are three controls entering the hub.

Comment: @Criggie On this pics I see that front mech is regular single chainring. Both cables from the shifters goes to the rear hub + one cable from braking lever to the drum brake in rear hub.

Comment: Ok, I've found sth similar with two shifters. : https://coastalcycles.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/vintage-schwinn-track-frame-w-5-speed-sturmey-archer-hub-2/

Comment: It looks like SA AT5 http://www.sturmey-archerheritage.com/index.php?page=history-detail&id=145    http://sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer_5-spd.html#changes

Comment: The style of lettering on the decals makes me think it is a late 80's or 90's bike. (I live where Gazelle bikes are common.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appearance is alloy shell and 70mm drum which would be a Sturmey-Archer AT 5 , which was made mid 80's thru late 90's with dual lever shifters . A version was also made with just 3 gears .

Comment: Posted it in comment earlier but yes, this is probably an answer:) It should be noted that shifters are without big doubt original.

Answer (score 0):

The sturmey archer 5 speed has gear chain skewers in both sides of the hub. though there was a dedicated 2 cable single leaver to go with this a pair of shifters like these designed to operate derailleur gears can be made to work.